# jQuery Slideshow - Hiding Other Slides While One Is Active

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a really simple slideshow using jQuery. I first tried with 
 `position: absolute` to get this working, but this was bugging the layout, so I've now decided to try to use `display:` instead.

I currently have this code:

```html
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
     $(".slideshow > a").hide();
        $('.slideshow a:first').css('display', 'block');

     setInterval(function() {
      $('.slideshow > a').css('display', 'none');
      $('.slideshow a:first').css('display', 'block').show().next().show().end().appendTo('.slideshow');
     }, 3000);
    </script>

    <div class="slideshow">
         <a href="">Hello 1</a>
         <a href="">Hello 2</a>
         <a href="">Hello 3</a>
         <a href="">Hello 4</a>
    </div>
```

How can I make it so it only displays `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` in order instead of it having to display multiple items at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `class` to change the `display` and calculate the index of the next `a` which is going to be showed.

```js
let $a = $(".slideshow a");
$a.eq(0).addClass("show");

setInterval(function() {
  let index = $(".show").index();
  let next = (index + 1) % 4;
  $a.removeClass("show").eq(next).addClass("show");
}, 3000);
```

```css
.slideshow a {
  display: none;
}

.slideshow a.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="slideshow">
  <a href="">Hello 1</a>
  <a href="">Hello 2</a>
  <a href="">Hello 3</a>
  <a href="">Hello 4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That indeed works perfectly. Thanks for helping out, Hikarunomemory!

Comment: No problem, glad to help.